# Adding a new record to a typed dataset error

Tags: c#, ado.net, msdn

I have used the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5ycd1034(v=vs.100).aspx) for adding a new record to my DataSet. I have even used the same variable names to keep it simple.

C# Code

```
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow newCustomersRow =
northwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow();

    newCustomersRow.CustomerID = "5";
    newCustomersRow.CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste";

    northwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
```

The error I am getting is `The name 'northwindDataSet1' does not exist in the current context`

I find this odd as I am using the code straight from  MSDN.

My DataSet is called NorthwindDataSet, the table is called Customers. I have tried `northwindDataSet` but still the same error.

Comment: You obviously didn't declare `northwindDataSet1` in your code, at least not in the appropriate level.

Comment: There is no defination of northwindDataSet1 appears to me in this code

Comment: (This has nothing to do with ASP.NET - I've changed the tags to reflect the fact that it's more to do with ADO.NET.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code example snippet in MSDN isn't designed to be *complete*. You need a variable called `northwindDataSet1` in order to use this snippet.

For example, you could just use:

```
NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet1 = new NorthwindDataSet();
```

... although more likely you'd want to fetch it from a database with a data adapter, or some such.

It's important that you try to really *understand* the code being presented. Even if you're new to typed data sets, it should be clear that this is trying to use an existing variable - which means that in order to use the code, you have to *have* that variable.

If you're sufficiently new to C# that you don't understand the syntax being used here (and there's nothing wrong with being new, of course) I would suggest that you start off learning the basics of C# before you move onto database access. That way when you're learning about more advanced topics, you'll be in a better position. Learning one thing at a time is much more efficient than trying to learn everything in one go.

> My DataSet is called NorthwindDataSet

What *exactly* do you mean by that? Do you mean your data set *type*, or do you have a *property* called `NorthwindDataSet` somewhere? Basically something needs to create an instance of the data set type at some point... it's not clear how far you've got with that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although for some reason the data isnt being saved abck to the database.  NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet1 = new NorthwindDataSet();
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow newCustomersRow =
northwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow();

newCustomersRow.CustomerID = "5";
newCustomersRow.CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste";

northwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);

        northwindDataSet1.Customers.AcceptChanges();

Comment: @JoshuaHornby: Where within that code did you expect it to be saved? You're not even specifying a database to talk to. I suggest you take a step back and read through a *complete* ADO.NET tutorial.

Comment: Can you point my into the right director for code examples of specifying a database?

Comment: @JoshuaHornby: No, because that would be ignoring my advice to look at a more holistic tutorial. There are plenty of full tutorials available - or books including them. You'll make *much* more progress if you learn about things in a well-designed order, instead of just picking off one problem at a time. You might also want to consider a newer data access technology such as Entity Framework - personally I'd rather not touch data sets with a barge pole at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Define it first like

```
NorthwindDataSet northwindDataSet1 = new NorthwindDataSet();
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow newCustomersRow =
northwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow();

newCustomersRow.CustomerID = "5";
newCustomersRow.CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste";

northwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
```